# Java Inheritance and avoiding constant use of instanceof

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, instanceof

I have three classes, an abstract User and two specific: NormalUser which holds an ArrayList of one or more Address objects which can be different (domestic, international, custom etc.) and then the Admin class which has a method which returns true . They both contain more methods which are unrelated to each other.

```
abstract class User{
    public User(String username, String pw){
 ...

}

public class NormalUser extends User{
...
    private ArrayList<Address> addresses;

...

    public void addAdress(ArrayList<Address> address){
        addresses.addAll(address);
}

public class Admin extends User{

...
    public boolean getIsAdmin(){
        return true;
  }
}
```

Now in another class if I make 4 user objects like this for example:

```
    ArrayList<User> users;

    users.add(new NormalUser( "1", "pw");
    users.add(new NormalUser( "2", "pw");
    users.add(new NormalUser( "3", "pw");
    users.add(new NormalUser( "4", "pw");
    users.add(new Admin("5", "pw"));
    users.add(new NormalUser( "6", "pw");
```

And say I want to use the addAddress method in NormalUser, then I have to downcast the specfic user in users to NormalUser, before I can use the addAddress method in NormalUser like this:

```
     if (user instanceof NormalUser){
        NormalUser normal = (NormalUser) user;
        normal.addAddress(...)
        }
```

The reason why I would like both NormalUser and Admin to be a User is so I can process them together when logging in.

I thought of adding the addEmail to the User class and then overriding it in the NormalUser class, but I would have to do that for every method in the NormalUser class, plus Admin would inherit it from the User as well, when it doesnt need that functionality.

**Question 1**: Is there a better way to do this as I heard using instanceof is a bad thing? and I would have to use instanceof every time I use a method that is specific to the NormalUser class.

**Quesiton 2**: Is an ArrayList of object Addresses the best way to link the RegularUser to specific addresses/(Objects)?

There is no database involved right now.

So for example user a has 2 addresses one domestic and one international, and user b just has a domestic address, user c has a domestic and a custom address etc.

Thanks.

PS. I've searched the previous posts extensively but havent found a solution. In both my Java books they both show examples of using instanceof but no mention of it being a bad practice.

Comment: As to this specific case, I'm afraid I can't really say which is better, but no, `instanceof` is not by definition a bad thing. You just shouldn't overuse it when polymorphism is more appropriate.

Comment: Related to the `instanceof`: you should rethink your design such that you never call `addAddress` on a basic `User`.  You should only call such a method when you are in a block of code that is specifically designed for `NormalUser`.

Comment: is there any good reason for Admins to not have adresses?

Comment: @soulcheck it's not just addresses, its like 10 different methods :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) - a bit clumsy and slightly unreadable, but probably the best solution for your problem.

Actually your solution with pushing `addEmail` to base class isn't that bad. Simply provide an empty implementation in base `User` and override in `RegularUser`. If you want to check whether given `User` instance supports adding e-mails, provide another method like `supportsAddEmail` returning `false` by default and `true` when overriding `addEmail`.

Comment: But wont Admin inherit the addAddress (even if its empty)?

Comment: Yes, this means you can call `Admin.addEmail()` which does nothing (no-op). That's the reason why I suggest `supportsAddEmail`, but it doesn't really look like a good idea. Bit isn't this exactly what you want? Add e-mail if user is `NormalUser`, do nothing otherwise.

Comment: I think adding `addEmail` to the base class is a good idea, and harmless. Regarding its no-op nature, you can think of it as "someone has told the Admin object about an email address, and if the admin doesn't care, so be it." Where it gets uglier is if you need to put `getEmail()` in the base class; in this case, certain implementations would have to throw an exception, which I find ugly. If you do this, at least have a method like `supportsGetEmail()`. Best would be if call sites know which User subclass they have, so you can add `getEmail()` to NormalUser only.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest solution is to create a class UserList that would contain a list of NormalUser and a list of Admin. An instance of the class UserList would replace the original list. The class UserList could provide some methods such as:

- User getUser(index i)  // implemented with the two lists
- User removeUser(index i)  // implemented with  the two lists
- NormalUser getNormalUser(index i)  // implemented with the normal user list
- NormalUser removeNormalUser(index i) // implemented with the normal user list
- Admin getAdmin(index i)  // implemented with the admin user list
- Admin removeAdmin(index i)  // implemented with the admin user list
- ....

All the code for handling the appropriate lists would be encapsulated in the UserList class.  You could have methods that use both lists or only one list, depending on what you need to do with the users.  Classes that interact with UserList would not know if there is only a single or two lists inside UserList.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil, it seems like a good idea to me, although I would have liked not having to create a new classes just to hold the lists. I'm new at Java but if for example I had a animal superclass, then a cat and dog subclass. If I had  list of animals with dogs and cats, and I wanted to call bark() on the dogs, then I would have to create a list of dogs to do that correct? - just seems counter intuitive to me :/

Comment: Hello.  If I where you, I would create (1) a list for cats and (2) a list for dogs.   Consider that you have 10000 dogs  and 10000 cats.  If you separate the lists, it will be much faster to find all the dogs, then if you would have a single list with 20000 animals mixed together.  When you need to call a method such as bark() you just need to process the list of dogs instead of processing 20 000 animals and having to check if they are dogs or cats before calling bark(). Performance should be much better with two lists if you have many elements.